# How do I get the last item from a list using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why does column `1st_from_end` contain null:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a b c d',)], ['s',])
df.select(   split(df.s, ' ')[0].alias('0th'),
             split(df.s, ' ')[3].alias('3rd'),
             split(df.s, ' ')[-1].alias('1st_from_end')
         ).show()
```

[image]
I thought using `[-1]` was a pythonic way to get the last item in a list. How come it doesn't work in pyspark?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For **Spark 2.4+**, use [pyspark.sql.functions.**element_at**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#element_at), see below from the documentation:

> element_at(array, index) - Returns element of array at given (1-based) index. If index < 0, accesses elements from the last to the first. Returns NULL if the index exceeds the length of the array.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import element_at, split, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([('a b c d',)], ['s',])

df.withColumn('arr', split(df.s, ' ')) \
  .select( col('arr')[0].alias('0th')
         , col('arr')[3].alias('3rd')
         , element_at(col('arr'), -1).alias('1st_from_end')
     ).show()

+---+---+------------+
|0th|3rd|1st_from_end|
+---+---+------------+
|  a|  d|           d|
+---+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 20):

If you're using Spark >= 2.4.0 see jxc's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085625/7098262).

In Spark < 2.4.0, dataframes API didn't support `-1` indexing on arrays, but you could write your own UDF or use built-in `size()` function, for example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import size
>>> splitted = df.select(split(df.s, ' ').alias('arr'))
>>> splitted.select(splitted.arr[size(splitted.arr)-1]).show()
+--------------------+
|arr[(size(arr) - 1)]|
+--------------------+
|                   d|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. My solution was a bit more hokey than that: `reverse(split(reverse(df.s), ' ')[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `getItem` method, which allows you to get the i-th item of an ArrayType column. Here's how I would do it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, size

df.withColumn("Splits", split(col("s"), " ")) \
    .withColumn("0th", col("Splits").getItem(0)) \
    .withColumn("3rd", col("Splits").getItem(3)) \
    .withColumn("1st_from_end", col("Splits").getItem(size(col("Splits"))-1)) \
    .drop("Splits")
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on jamiet 's solution, we can simplify even further by removing a `reverse`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, reverse

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a b c d',)], ['s',])
df.select(   split(df.s, ' ')[0].alias('0th'),
             split(df.s, ' ')[3].alias('3rd'),
             reverse(split(df.s, ' '))[-1].alias('1st_from_end')
         ).show()
```

Comment: shouldn't be reverse(split(df.s, ' '))[0].alias('1st_from_end')  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small trick to use column expressions. It's quite neat because there is no use of udf. But still the functional interface makes it quite likable for me.

```py
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, size
from pyspark.sql import Column
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


data = [
    ('filename', 's3:/hello/no.csv'),
    ('filename', 's3:/hello/why.csv')
]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('path', StringType(), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)



def expression_last_item_of_array(split_column: str, split_delimeter: str) -> Column:
    """
        Given column name and delimeter, return expression 
        for splitting string and returning last item of the array.
        
        Args:
            split_column: str
            split_delimeter: str
        
        Returns:
            pysaprk.sql.Column
    """
    expression = split(split_column, split_delimeter)
    n = size(expression)
    last = expression.getItem(n - 1)
    return last, n

last, n = expression_last_item_of_array('path', '/')
df.show(),
df.select(last.alias('last_element'), n.alias('n_items')).show(), df.select(last.alias('last_element')).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------------+
|    name|             path|
+--------+-----------------+
|filename| s3:/hello/no.csv|
|filename|s3:/hello/why.csv|
+--------+-----------------+

+------------+-------+
|last_element|n_items|
+------------+-------+
|      no.csv|      3|
|     why.csv|      3|
+------------+-------+

+------------+
|last_element|
+------------+
|      no.csv|
|     why.csv|
+------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

Create your own udf would look like this

```
    def get_last_element(l):
        return l[-1]
    get_last_element_udf = F.udf(get_last_element)

    df.select(get_last_element(split(df.s, ' ')).alias('1st_from_end')
```