# Pyspark - Split a column and take n elements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to take a column and split a string using a character. As per usual, I understood that the method split would return a list, but when coding I found that the returning object had only the methods getItem or getField with the following descriptions from the API:

> ```python
> @since(1.3)   
> def getItem(self, key):
>     """
>     An expression that gets an item at position ``ordinal`` out of a list,
>     or gets an item by key out of a dict.
>
>
> @since(1.3)
> def getField(self, name):
>     """
>     An expression that gets a field by name in a StructField.
> ```

Obviously this doesnt meet my requirements, for example for the text within the column "A_B_C_D" I would like to split between "A_B_C_" and "D" in two different columns.

This is the code I'm using

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col, split
df_test=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db_test.table_test")
#Applying the transformations to the data

split_col=split(df_test['Full_text'],'_')
df_split=df_test.withColumn('Last_Item',split_col.getItem(3))
```

Find an example:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col, split
l = [("Item1_Item2_ItemN"),("FirstItem_SecondItem_LastItem"),("ThisShouldBeInTheFirstColumn_ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
datax = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(fullString=x))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(datax)
split_col=split(df['fullString'],'_')
df=df.withColumn('LastItemOfSplit',split_col.getItem(2))
```

Result:

```python
fullString                                                LastItemOfSplit
Item1_Item2_ItemN                                            ItemN
FirstItem_SecondItem_LastItem                                LastItem
ThisShouldBeInTheFirstColumn_ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn     null
```

My expected result would be having always the last item

```python
fullString                                                LastItemOfSplit
Item1_Item2_ItemN                                            ItemN
FirstItem_SecondItem_LastItem                                LastItem
ThisShouldBeInTheFirstColumn_ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn  ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn
```

Comment: What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: You can pass in a regexp pattern to `split`. Perhaps `split(df_test["Full_text"], r"_(?=.$)")` would work.

Comment: @Psidom I would like another way to access the results of the split, not by the index number, like the last element of the resultant list (the size varies within the data).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `getItem(size - 1)` to get the last item from the arrays:

*Example*:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']], [['E', 'F']]], ['split'])
df.show()
+------------+
|       split|
+------------+
|[A, B, C, D]|
|      [E, F]|
+------------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('lastItem', df.split.getItem(F.size(df.split) - 1)).show()
+------------+--------+
|       split|lastItem|
+------------+--------+
|[A, B, C, D]|       D|
|      [E, F]|       F|
+------------+--------+
```

For your case:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col, split, size
df_test=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db_test.table_test")
#Applying the transformations to the data

split_col=split(df_test['Full_text'],'_')
df_split=df_test.withColumn('Last_Item',split_col.getItem(size(split_col) - 1))
```

Comment: In newer versions of pyspark 'element_at' should be used instead of getItems(size( as jxc states in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467936/how-do-i-get-the-last-item-from-a-list-using-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a regular expression pattern to [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split).

The following would work for your example:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions split

split_col=split(df['fullString'], r"_(?=.+$)")
df = df.withColumn('LastItemOfSplit', split_col.getItem(1))
df.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
#|fullString                                              |LastItemOfSplit            |
#+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
#|Item1_Item2_ItemN                                       |Item2                      |
#|FirstItem_SecondItem_LastItem                           |SecondItem                 |
#|ThisShouldBeInTheFirstColumn_ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn|ThisShouldBeInTheLastColumn|
#+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

The pattern means the following:

- `_` the literal underscore
- `(?=.+$)` positive look-ahead for anything (`.`) until the end of the string `$`

This will split the string on the last underscore. Then call `.getItem(1)` to get the item at index 1 in the resultant list.

Comment: I got a similar problem where I'd like to split on the last '/'. `r"/(?=.+$)"` does not do the job :/. Can you please help me out?