# PySpark equivalent for lambda function in Pandas UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have written a data preprocessing codes in Pandas UDF in PySpark. I'm using lambda function to extract a part of the text from all the records of a column.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
@pandas_udf("string", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def get_X(col):
      return col.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1] if len(x.split(',')) > 0 else x)

df = df.withColumn('X', get_first_name(df.Y))
```

This is working fine and giving the desired results. But I need to write the same piece of logic in Spark equivalent code. Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem per se, but `len(x.split(',')) > 0` is always `True` unless `x` is `None`, in which case you can't call `split()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one function [substring_index](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) is enough for this particular task:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index

df = spark.createDataFrame([(x,) for x in ['f,l', 'g', 'a,b,cd']], ['c1'])

df2.withColumn('c2', substring_index('c1', ',', -1)).show()                                                                 
+------+---+
|    c1| c2|
+------+---+
|   f,l|  l|
|     g|  g|
|a,b,cd| cd|
+------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following DataFrame `df`:

```
df.show()
# +-------------+
# |     BENF_NME|
# +-------------+
# |    Doe, John|
# |          Foo|
# |Baz, Quux,Bar|
# +-------------+
```

You can simply use [`regexp_extract()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) to select the first name:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
df.withColumn('First_Name', regexp_extract(df.BENF_NME, r'(?:.*,\s*)?(.*)', 1)).show()
# +-------------+----------+
# |     BENF_NME|First_Name|
# +-------------+----------+
# |    Doe, John|      John|
# |          Foo|       Foo|
# |Baz, Quux,Bar|       Bar|
# +-------------+----------+
```

If you don't care about possible leading spaces, [`substring_index()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) provides a simple alternative to your original logic:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index
df.withColumn('First_Name', substring_index(df.BENF_NME, ',', -1)).show()
# +-------------+----------+
# |     BENF_NME|First_Name|
# +-------------+----------+
# |    Doe, John|      John|
# |          Foo|       Foo|
# |Baz, Quux,Bar|       Bar|
# +-------------+----------+
```

In this case the first row's `First_Name` has a leading space:

```
df.withColumn(...).collect()[0]
# Row(BENF_NME=u'Doe, John', First_Name=u' John'
```

If you still want to use a custom function, you need to create a user-defined function (UDF) using [`udf()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
get_first_name = udf(lambda s: s.split(',')[-1], StringType())
df.withColumn('First_Name', get_first_name(df.BENF_NME)).show()
# +-------------+----------+
# |     BENF_NME|First_Name|
# +-------------+----------+
# |    Doe, John|      John|
# |          Foo|       Foo|
# |Baz, Quux,Bar|       Bar|
# +-------------+----------+
```

Note that UDFs are slower than the built-in Spark functions, especially Python UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to implement [if-then-else logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else):

First [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) the column, then compute its [`size`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size). If the size is greater than 0, [take the last element from the split array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467936/how-do-i-get-the-last-item-from-a-list-using-pyspark). Otherwise, return the original column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, size, when

def get_first_name(col):
    col_split = split(col, ',')
    split_size = size(col_split)
    return when(split_size > 0, col_split[split_size-1]).otherwise(col)
```

As an example, suppose you had the following DataFrame:

```
df.show()
#+---------+
#| BENF_NME|
#+---------+
#|Doe, John|
#|  Madonna|
#+---------+
```

You can call the new function just as before:

```
df = df.withColumn('First_Name', get_first_name(df.BENF_NME))
df.show()
#+---------+----------+
#| BENF_NME|First_Name|
#+---------+----------+
#|Doe, John|      John|
#|  Madonna|   Madonna|
#+---------+----------+
```